# OpenLayers 3 Vector wrong position with zoom

Tags: javascript, maps, openstreetmap, openlayers-3

I try draw a vector image on map using OpenLayers 3. The image behaves strange when using zoom on the map. To demonstrate this made a jsffidle: http://jsfiddle.net/aderbas/8kpoqoow/

```
 var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
        opacity: 0.75,
        src: '//cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pictype-free-vector-icons/16/location-alt-32.png'
      }))
    });
```

To happen just use the zoom in/out. Does anyone know why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't make it clear what you mean by "behaves strange", but I'm assuming it's about the marker "floating" after zooming in and out. This is caused by the fact that you're using a custom marker image that has its tip on the bottom, but OpenLayers by default sets the centre of the icon to be in its middle (since it has no way of inferring where the "pointy" side is).

You can easily solve this problem by defining the anchor. There are multiple ways to [specify where the anchor should be](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.7.0/apidoc/ol.style.Icon.html), using the `anchor` is probably most straightforward in this case:

```js
var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
    opacity: 0.75,

    anchor: [0.5, 1], // middle on the X axis, bottom on the Y axis

    src: '//cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pictype-free-vector-icons/16/location-alt-32.png'
  }))
});
```

Here's your updated JSFiddle that shows new behaviour with anchor defined: http://jsfiddle.net/kryger/hv8w4o3u/2/

Comment: I saw in the documentation, but did not have time to review. Thank you solved my problem.